# Databricks where can I find the change history of a JOB schedule?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I need help locating where the history of a JOB's scheduled time change is stored in Databricks. I looked in the overwatch.job tables, but I didn't find anything. Is there more somewhere I can see this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to audit the access (updates in particular) to a job/workflow in Databricks.

Databricks recently added a built-in collection of "System Tables" that provides the data for these types of audit scenarios. You do need to ENABLE this feature first by following the documentation laid out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/system-tables/

And in this case you are going to be interested in the Audit Logs (`system.access.audit`) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/system-tables/audit-logs

> Limitation note: No support for real-time monitoring. Data is updated throughout the day. If you don’t see a log for a recent event, check back later.

Then the query you might run to interogate changes made against a particular job/workflow would be:

```sql
SELECT
  request_params.job_id,
  get_json_object(request_params.new_settings, '$.name') as job_name,
  get_json_object(request_params.new_settings, '$.schedule') as job_schedule,
  user_identity.email as user_email,
  event_time
FROM system.access.audit
WHERE 
  event_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
  AND service_name = 'jobs'
  AND action_name IN ('create', 'update')
  AND workspace_id = '<YOUR_WORKSPACE_ID>'
  AND request_params.job_id = '<YOUR_JOB_ID>'
ORDER BY event_time DESC
;
```